# Do I need install php5-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I have a wordpress site on windows server. I moved it on ubuntu server but take an error "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

I did some research for fix it and founded "you must install php5-mysql pacakage". Why? I have already installed php-mysql package.

important note: There is good working another wordpress site on same server.

important note: Nginx - MySql - Php7.0 are installed on ubuntu server

please help me?

Comment: If use use PHP5, you should install php5-mysql.

Comment: no i used php7.

Comment: @Evgeniy Just as an FYI, it's better to use mysqlnd

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a way to talk to MySQL. There's only two ways to do that

1. Through the MySQL Client (i.e. `php5-mysql`). This is the older way to do it. PHP unbundled MySQL so this route also requires you to install `mysql-client` (or whatever equivalent your distro uses) since it talks to MySQL though the client.
2. Through the [MySQL Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php) (i.e. `php5-mysqlnd`). This way is preferred, since it is a core part of PHP now. This way PHP directly communicates with MySQL without an intermediary. Also, some parts of `mysqli` work better with this installed

It sounds like this is Ubuntu and PHP7. So you might need something like `php7-mysqlnd`

Comment: Hi, how can i install it?

Comment: I think: sudo apt-get install php7-mysqlnd

Comment: i received "Unable to locate package php7-mysqlnd"

Comment: Never mind. Apparently that's a RedHat convention. `php7-mysql` apparently is mysqlnd in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress only checks for availability of `mysql_*` functions. If you are getting this error they are not available.

If you really installed `php-mysql` metapackage (which I hope actually installs `php7.0-mysql`) and you have `mysql` mod available in apache `mods_available` folder, it's not simply not enabled. You need to add a link to `mods_enabled` and restart the server.

BTW, you can check enabled mods with `php_info()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't use apache server, i use nginx

Comment: Then the MySQL mod should be enabled in NGINX.

Comment: how can i do it? @Boris i have a important note "There is good working another wordpress site on same server."

Comment: @Boris Shchegolev Apache and NGINX don't know about DB server. It should be enabled in PHP

Comment: It's important to note that [PHP7 removed mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling, that you have 2 PHP installations on your server, namely php5.6 and php7.0. Since there is presence of php7.0 and you do not seem to have used (based on the way you described the problem) custom source.list to achieve this I presume that you have Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

The following commands on your Ubuntu 16.04 server should resolve this issue for you:

```
apt install php7.0-mysql
service php7.0-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

However, if you indeed have active php5 installed and activated, you should check if your php-fpm pool is using a different version. You can check this by looking into file:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Additionally, you can update your question with additional details, by running the following commands on your server and sharing with us their output:

```
lsb_release -a (determines Ubuntu version)
which php (determines which php is loaded in the command line)
service --status-all (shows installed services and their status)
```

Based on the details you have provided I assume that there is some mixup with the PHP packages, and this should help you to get rid of the problem. Please note, that the following command will most likely influence other website on the same server, and you should understand what this command does before you run it. In essence it will remove all php packages you have right now, and then install back only php7.0 packages.

```
apt update

apt purge --auto-remove php-common php-fpm php-mysql php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache  php7.0-readline

apt autoremove -y
apt autoclean -y

apt install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mbstring php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-cli php7.0-curl
```

Comment: Hi, installed packages; 
php-common                                      install
php-fpm                                         install
php-mysql                                       install
php7.0-cli                                      install
php7.0-common                                   install
php7.0-fpm                                      install
php7.0-json                                     install
php7.0-mysql                                    install
php7.0-opcache                                  install
php7.0-readline                                 install

Comment: I updated answer based on your input, but I still need to know which Ubuntu version you run.. and which services you have installed / run..

Comment: thank you everybody, my issue resolved. I updated to last version my wordpress site before moving site. :)